# Coding a windows desktop app (.exe) - does this sound right?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, google-maps, desktop

I'm an intern working on a project at work.  My boss he doesn't have a technical background (nor does any of the other employees at work), so I don't really have anyone to ask.

Right now, we've got a bunch of excel files that contains data (shipping data). Usually, we take the data in excel and then manually transpose the data onto a map.  For example, we might take a screenshot from Google Maps of "Location X" and then annotate:

- A red circle with a 10 in it placed on Building A corresponds to 10 shipments of ketchup at Building A
- A green square with a 5 in it placed on Building B corresponds to 5 shipments of apples at Building B
- A black arrow on Building C means Building C received the most shipments.
- and so on...

Some more information:

- There are about 30 different symbols in total
- There are > 100 locations. The address of the locations are given in the data file.
- Each diagram is for one particular week (or month).

I want to automate this process, making it as user friendly for the other employees at work.  Here's my thought process on how to develop this app

- We only use Windows (Windows 7 in particular) based systems
- I want to develop a desktop app. in Visual Studio using either VB.net or C# (not sure which one is better).
- The app will take an excel file and extract the data from it.  It will overlay any symbols on the image of the location.
- The location of the image can either be from a user inputted screenshot or taken programmatically from Google Maps (depending if Google Maps integration is possible).

My questions are:

- Is Visual Studio + VB.net/C# a good choice for this project?
- Will it be able to process excel files? (or I am going in a completely wrong direction).
- Is Google Maps integration possible?
- Any suggestions?

(Also, my boss said we can hire a contractor to do this work, but I'll really like to give this a try).

Comment: Sounds interesting, and certainly do-able in C# or VB.Net. Neither is better, though you may find more example code online in C#. The only bit that concerns me is you say the _address_ of the locations is given in the data file. Somehow you will need to translate this to Lat and Long to position it on the map, or something similar. Bit of research required around that bit, but that's independent of the language choice.

Comment: @peterG if he has an address, he can get the lat and long with an API call.

Comment: I would suggest VB.NET : this language is less commun than C#, but it will allow you to keep quite a lot of your VBA code if your excel files are "clean VBA". Otherwise... whatever you do in excel you can do in .NET, and .NET (VB or C#) is definitely a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

> Is Visual Studio + VB.net/C# a good choice for this project?

Yes, you can use any of those languages to accomplish your goals. I'd suggest using C#, because I personally think it's simpler to learn, more intuitive, you have more tools, examples and docs in the web to play around (not that is not possible with VB). Using C# is a personal opinion, but answering to your question: yes, you can use them.

> Will it be able to process excel files? (or I am going in a completely wrong direction).

Both languages have features to load `.xls` (as well as many other formats) and read and process data from it. Actually, your excel would **act as a database**, since your data is stored there. A good possibility is to create a database in a server (where every computer could access) and start creating forms so your team would use it to input data (no more excel needed). But this is just a possibility, something to think about, it's not a requirement for now, you can still use your excel.

> Is Google Maps integration possible?

Yes. Google provides many APIs for integration. One option is using their [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=vi), which allows you to provide location or lat/long, configure zoom, markers and even paths to connect these markers. You do an **HTTP Request** and get an image (by default they give **PNG** but you can provide the format you want).

See this simple example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400.

Under free usage (the day I'm writing this), there is a daily usage limit up to 25000 requests and 640x640 maximum resolution to avoid abuse, but if you need to make more than 25000 requests per day or need a better resolution, you can acquire a license.

You can [check here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/usage-limits) for more details.

---

It won't be an easy task, but it's a fun challenge. If you are not familiar with C# and programming languages, you could start by creating a small system to allow your team to input everything they input in your system, so you could store in a database and stop using excel, just as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Glad to know I'm headed in the right direction. I actually do have a bit of experience with C as well as web dev (and a bit with Google maps). I do like your idea about the database - although everything is on Excel now, I think it'll be nice to move all the new data to a database format such as Microsoft Access